# Flutter: The element type 'String' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'

Tags: flutter, dart

First off, I am really really new

I do not understand why these two errors are appearing :
1.The element type 'String' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'.
2.Expected to find ']'.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import './qs.dart';
import 'answer.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  //override is basically useless
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _MyAppState();
  } //refers to the particular class
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  //an underscore means that the particular class can only be called
  //within htat particular file
  var _questionindex = 0;
  @override
  void _answerQuestion() {
    setState(() {
      _questionindex = _questionindex + 1;
    });
    print(_questionindex);
  } //helps in reloading the state whenever the values of a vriable is updated

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var questions = [
      {
        'questiontext':'What\s your Age group?',
      'answers':['No','No','No','No'],
      },
      {
        'questiontext':'What\s your profession?',
      'answers':['student','teacher','government official','[private enterprise']
      },
      {
        'questiontext':'At what time do you get up?',
      'answers':['4am-6am','6am-7am','7am-8am','After 8am']}
      ];

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text(
            'Dragons be here',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: "Arial",
              fontSize: 35,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
          titleSpacing: 1.0,
          centerTitle: true,
          shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(bottom: Radius.circular(30)),
          ),
        ),

        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            qs(
              questions[_questionindex]['questiontext'] as String,
            ),
            ...(questions[_questionindex]['answers']) as List<String>.map((answer){
              Answer(_answerQuestion,answer);
            }).toList()
  
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


   }

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class qs extends StatelessWidget {
  final String questionStr;
  qs(this.questionStr);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Text(
        questionStr,
      ),
    );
  }
}

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Answer extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback ansk;
  //idk y but function is snot working, 
  //if it is not wrking use Voidcallback
  final String gimme_da_answer;

  Answer(this.ansk, this.gimme_da_answer);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: ansk,
        child: Text(gimme_da_answer),
        style: ButtonStyle(
          backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.amberAccent),
          foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.blueAccent),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Also i did not exactly understand what maps in dart was, would be really halpful if someone gave a breif overview

If you have read till here THANK YOU

Comment: On which line you are getting this error?

Comment: @Diwyansh Line 73 is where both the errors are shown
...(questions[_questionindex]['answers']) as List<String>.map((answer){
  Answer(_answerQuestion,answer);
            }).toList()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
...(questions[_questionindex]['answers']) as List<String>.map((answer){
              Answer(_answerQuestion,answer);
            }).toList()
```

there are 2 reasons why the above code is causing you problems.

1. `List<String>.map(...` is confusing dart, because it thinks you are calling some method on `List<String>`, to fix this, surround it with another pair of parenthesis

```
...((questions[_questionindex]['answers']) as List<String>).map((answer){
              Answer(_answerQuestion,answer);
            }).toList()
```

2. the map method doesn't return anything, you most likely forgot to add a return statement, to fix this just add the return statement:

```
...((questions[_questionindex]['answers']) as List<String>).map((answer){
              return Answer(_answerQuestion,answer);
            }).toList()
```

Regarding **Expected to find ']'.** Sorry, but after copying and pasting your code in my editor, I did not get this error... Would you mind showing a screenshot of exactly where the squiggly line appears?

Finally I will attempt to explain what a map is:

a map is just a set of key-value pairs, that is to say, every item in a map has   some name and some value, similar to a normal variable. A map's syntax looks like this:

```
Map<TypeA, TypeB> myMap = {
  key1: value1,
  key2: value2,
  key3: value3,
  ...
  keyN: valueN,
};
```

Where typeA is the type of the key and typeB is the type of the value, so for example:

```
Map<int, bool> myMap = {
  4: false,
  99: true,
  1927: false,
  777777: false,
  7: true,
};
```

above, the map's keys have an int type and the map's values have a bool type.

Of course, you can use `dynamic` in order to have different types of keys:

```
Map<String, dynamic> myMap = {
  'some string': 1,
  'some other string': true,
  'something else': ['aa','vv','gg',1],
};
```

above the type of the keys is always string, but the values type changes, for `some string`, the type is int, for `some other string` the type is bool, and for `something else`, the type is `List`, the list there has 3 strings and one int.

your `questions` variable is actually a list of maps:

```
var questions = [
      {
        'questiontext':'What\s your Age group?',
      'answers':['No','No','No','No'],
      },
      {
        'questiontext':'What\s your profession?',
      'answers':['student','teacher','government official','[private enterprise']
      },
      {
        'questiontext':'At what time do you get up?',
      'answers':['4am-6am','6am-7am','7am-8am','After 8am']}
      ];
```

these are the types:

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> questions = [
  {
    String: String,
    String: List<String>
  }
]
```

so for example, `var x = questions[0]['answers']`, x will be dynamic, because the values of your map are dynamic.

Hopefully this explanation makes everything a bit clearer?

Comment: Thank you sir, the code works now, As for the ']' error, I don't understand why it came up, it has disappeared now. Also now i understood what map means. THANKS AGAIN